# What is the most efficient for text and images, Uiwebview or UITextView?

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview, uitextview

I have a Uitableview that contain cells which I am going to use to display some topics. Each topic has about two paragraphs and an image. To make it easier to maintain and not hardcode the data I have elected to use local html files which I load into a UIWebView in each cell.

Just from the way it is performing I can tell it needs some optimizing. After the WebView is loaded I have to resize the cells. Also if the table has a lot of topics it takes a few milliseconds that is noticeable.

Is there a better way to do this? The only other option is creating an attributed text in a TextView. I would really appreciate your thoughts on the best implementation and performance.

I have added an image showing some sample text in the webViews.